# Handling multiple forms and printing content

Tags: php

Hi I have an issue with the desired output of the following code.
I need to print `You hit T--` message whilst I see the `Form 2 is here!` message along with the button.

But now what happens is when I click `T--` button the message appears but the `Form 2 is here` content with button disappears. I need that message to be on the screen visible whilst the message `You hit T--` prints.

can some one pls highlight how to correct this? Many thanks for looking

here goes the code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one" style="width:300px; background:gray;">
            <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1">
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
                {echo "<input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='Two'>";}
                ?>
                <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="One">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="two" style="width:300px; background:yellow;">
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
            {echo "Form two is here!"; ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                <?php echo "<input type='submit' name='sendt' id='sendt' value='T--'>";}

                if(isset($_POST['sendt'])) {echo "You hit T--"; return;}
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this button T-- really needs to be a submit, or can it also be a button with an OnClick function?

Comment: @Marijke what exactly im trying to do is submit a form via T--. So once click on the button Two, in reality what I have in my programme is set of text boxes which will be validated and submit through T-- button. So I presume onClick won't work

Comment: OK, I think I get what you want now, but why do you want the form to be present after submitting it?

Comment: Assume if a user has entered a non expected value and then you print this as the error message. So when the error message is displayed on the screen, your text boxes aren't there and are invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got this right, is basically print that message when you post ether *sendtwo* or *sendt*.

```
if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']) || isset($_POST['sendt']))
{ echo "Form two is here!"; ?> }
```

Here's an [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DboJsS).

Comment: sorry if my question is ambiguous. Its not a function of AND I need. When 'sendtwo' is submitted (button Two) 'Form two is here' is printed along with the 'T--' button. Henceforth if I click button T--, then the previous text 'form 2 is here' disspears and only 'You hit T--' appears. What I need is to make sure when the button T-- is clicked both 'Form 2 is here' and 'You hit T--' to be visible.

Comment: @DKarolis, that's what my example does. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you and worked! May be I have not got your earlier explanation better. :) Thank you!